# How to change "was established"?

Tags: phrase-request

In my CV I described one of the companies I worked in the past as follows:

> The company **was established** by the participation of two Turkish companies in order to undertake works in Romania. In March 2003 the shareholders decided to dissolve the company for some reasons.

Is it correct? I think I should write something else instead of "was established."
What is your suggestion?

Comment: What do you think is wrong with *was established*?

Comment: Thanks. 
If you are a native speaker of English and it sounds "good" to you then no problem. It is grammatically correct, my concern is to find out a better expression.
For example,  Is "had been established" instead of "was established" better or not?
Many thanks.

Comment: The use of **was** is the most natural in this case. The use of **had been** more typically implies something else happening. In other words, *The company* ***had been*** *established* ***when*** *disaster struck . . .*

Comment: For what it's worth, I suspect that most people looking at this question (without looking at these comments) will think your concern is with the word **established** and not the verb tense.

Comment: You could lose the words **the participation of** without prejudicing the sentence. They add nothing to the meaning. The same is true of **for some reasons**.Clearly the shareholders would have had reasons. No point in mentioning it unless you specify the reasons.

Answer (score -1):

If  you mean that there used to be two companies that became one, then use the verb *consolidate* and the noun *merger*

> The company was [established as] **a merger of** two Turkish companies **conslidated** in order to undertake works in Romania.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mergers_and_acquisitions

Unless you meant: "The company was established by two Turkish companies in order to undertake works in Romania." = "The company was established by two Turkish companies participating in works in Romania." oooor "The company was established in effect of two Turkish companies' participation in works in Romania."

The expression "for some reasons" sounds too informal for a CV, I would leave the sentence as:

> In March 2003 the shareholders decided to dissolve the company.

Or to make it all shorter:

> The company was **a merger of** two Turkish companies **conslidated** in order to undertake works in Romania and later **split** by shareholders in March 2003.

I hope that helps, keep in mind I'm not an English native speaker though. Good luck with the job :)

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable answers, comments and contributions.